# Inviting app users to an app created event - is it possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a question regarding the creation of event invites by a facebook application, and the ability to invite the users who have approved that applications permissions to this event.

For example, we are a local nightclub who have an app allowing users to connect with the app to see who else is attending events etc, and keep up to date with information about the events we host. It would be ideal to be able to send an event invite to these users when we have special events or theme nights.

Currently the app has around 10,000 approved users.

Just really looking to find out if this is at all possible with the new open graph api? In particular the info provided at:

[Event API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)
[How To Use the Graph API to Manage Events](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/)

There does seem to be some confusion over what these posts say can be achieved, and what actually can be achieved.. unless those that I have previously spoken to are still basing their opinions on the old rest api.

Clarification and pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP POST if you use the `?users=` can only handle so many IDs before the length of the url overruns.  Since it's a post, you can specify the users parameter and then a comma separated list of ids for the value.  Try it out here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me